# How to use opencv to convert camera coordinates to latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, artoolkit

I'm working on augmented reality app in iOS, I have a scenario where I need to show objects with in the area where camera is covering. For this I have to convert the camera coordinates (bounds) to latitude and longitudes so that I can show the locations which are in same camera bounds.

Can we use OPenCV to for the same scenario where camera bounds can be converted to latitude and longitude

Comment: Unclear. How do you get the camera coordinates ? (please edit question to clarify, don't explain in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it may help to you.

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:<#(CLLocationDegrees)#>
                                                                                     longitude:<#(CLLocationDegrees)#> zoom:<#(float)#>];
mapview = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];
[self.view addSubview:mapview];
```

Please put lat,long,zoom value according to your requirement.